# SQL Server Recursive query to reverse engineer

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

Hi I need to write a query to back populate the CurrentQuantity field in the below table. I was originally thinking to use the while loop but I am wondering whether there is a way to write a recursive query to achieve this.

Bascially, the currentQuantity is next available currentQuantity + QuantityChanged of current record. So in this scenario, currentQuantity for ID -11 is CurrentQuantity of ID 20 which is -45 + QuantityChanged of current record which is (-5 * -1) and therefore it becomes -40.

ID column is always incremental so we can make an assumption on this.

I have been trying to write the recursive query using CTE but not sure where to start really... Any help will be highly appreciated !

[image]

Comment: Do you really need a recursion here? If you have some kind of baseline CurrentQuantity value (the first or the last) you could actually just sum all previous QuantityChanged values and add the result to the baseline for each row.

Comment: Always avoid to provide information that are not required to solve the problem. In this case the only required fields are ID and quantity fields. This way your post will be cleaner and more attractive for people to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not so great because your data is not really related. Managed to do it though - example code:

```
create table #data (id int, currentQuantity int, quantityChanged int);

insert into #data values (-30, NULL, -10);
insert into #data values (-24, NULL, -10);
insert into #data values (-22, NULL, -10);
insert into #data values (-11, NULL, -5);
insert into #data values (20, -45, -5);

select * from #data;

;with rcte as (
    select id, currentquantity, quantityChanged, 0 as Level
    from #data where id = 20
    union all
    select d.id, r.currentquantity + (d.quantityChanged * -1),
    d.quantityChanged, level + 1
    from #data d inner join rcte r on d.id < r.id
)
update #data
set currentQuantity = r.currentQuantity
from #data d
inner join rcte r
on d.id = r.id
inner join (
    select id, row_number() over (order by id desc) - 1 level
    from #data
) idl
on r.id = idl.id
and r.level = idl.level;

select * from #data;
```

That should produce what you are looking for.

NB: If you are using SQL Server > 2008 you could use the lead/lag functions to do this as well.